# Are there any differences, feature-wise, between Firefox for Mac and Firefox for Windows?

Tags: windows, switching, firefox, macos

I know that Chrome for Windows and Chrome for Mac are extremely similar. So similar that I only notice one difference for the Mac version: the green + button doesn't maximize. However, that can be remedied: http://maximizechrome.com. According to Google - I'm not sure where - there's only one difference: dragging highlighted text. I didn't notice this, but I don't usually drag highlighted text.

I don't use Firefox very often, but one thing I do appreciate is when an app behaves the same no matter your OS. I might even switch to Firefox if it does this. Thus, the question: Are there any differences, feature-wise, between Firefox for Mac and Firefox for Windows?

I mean real differences, not just things like the dropdown box styling provided by the OS.

Comment: similar to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45581/are-there-any-differences-feature-wise-between-safari-for-mac-and-safari-for-w

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Would you count platform related things, like differences in the menu structure and availability of certain extensions/themes to be real differences?

Comment: @JW01: Yes, but please don't list separate extensions as separate answers: just list one answer with all extensions. Also, the menu structure changes should be somewhat significant (not just if the browser rearranges the options)

Answer (score 1):

There is a significant issue in viewing PDFs on web sites.

Adobe Reader for Mac has a browser plug-in for viewing PDF files. It's never been compatible with FireFox for Mac, or Safari 5.1 and higher for Mac.

With FireFox on Mac, there's no reliable way to view a PDF file that's on a link from a Web site within FireFox itself. The best you can do is download it and open it using a PDF viewer on your Mac.

With Safari, you can view a PDF file in the browser window with Mac OS X's built-in PDF display capability. It works well enough, but it isn't the Adobe Reader Browser Plug-in, and that can create some problems with services that depend on the Adobe plug-in.

Comment: Yes but this has little to do with Firefox and all to do with the plug in for viewing PDFs more than likely written by Adobe for Windows browsers.

Comment: The Shubert PDF Browser plugin works well - it's free for non-commercial users (http://www.schubert-it.com/pluginpdf/)

Answer (score 1):

The core features of Firefox are the same between the different desktop platforms as noted on the [Firefox features page](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/features/).  The only differences noted between platforms would be optimzations specific for working with each platform. GUI implementation details to make Firefox look good and in place for the target OS environment.

Comment: I'm not asking which features are the same: I'm instead asking which features are *different*. There could be thousands of features that are the same; but there are most likely only a few features that are different.